# Cant connect to Oracle from Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can anyone help me to establish this Oracle SQL developer connection? 
If i have this connection string

```
<add name="sqlConnStringUrf" connectionString="workstation id=xxxx;packet 
 size=4096;user id=sa;data source=xxxx;persist security info=False;initial 
 catalog=yyy_UAT;pwd=12341234;" />
```

How can i fill this window to open the connection?

[image]

sorry for the basic question but i am pretty new at this.

Comment: Have you installed oracle server in your machine ? or your connecting remotely?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you don't connect to the sql developer. You can use this tool to connect to a Oracle DB.
Your user in the connection string looks like the sa user of sql server. is this right?

Answer (score 0):

For Basic Connection,

[image]

Password = Password of the user you entered in the USERNAME field.

Default Port is 1521.

Click Test to check connection. If it display successful, then click Save and Connect.

Comment: So in my connection string i do not have enough information to feel the window right?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your connection string above. You want to connect to an Oracle database, right? I believe you already have the connection details (oracle database name, server hostname, user id and password). You don't need the connection string if you already have them. If you don't know, ask your DBA or someone who create the database.

Comment: that the point i asked for credentials and he gave me only this, and i started wondering if maybe i do have all the information i need in that connection string

Comment: then go back to him and say you don't understand and ask him for a clear connection details.

Answer (score 0):

"user id=sa;" probably means that connect string is to a SQL Server Database. For that you need to load the JTDS drivers into sqldev. then there's a SQL Server tab that will show.

- To get jtds-1.3.1. Go here http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/
- Unzip that somewhere.
- In SQL Developer go to Tools -> Preferences ->
  Database -> Third party JDBC Drivers
- Click the “add entry” button
  Navigate to the jtds-x.x.x.jar file.
- Save and exit preferences.
- Close and restart SQL Developer
- Open “Add Connection” – there should now be a SQL Server tab.

Then you'll need the details of `data source=xxxx;` to fill in the dialog.